# Crop background and content uitextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to cut background of child if parent has border radius?
For instance:

```
CGRect r0 =CGRectMake(x, t, w, h);
/*Parent*/ UIView *par = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:r0];
[par.layer setCornerRadius:10.f];
/*Child*/ UITextField *child = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:r0];
[child setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[par addChild:child];
```

In this case corners fill with red color too. I do not want this.
Is there anyway to crop text and background of "child"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextFiled is a inherits UIView. So you can try to add following code

```
child.layer.cornerRadius = 10.;
child.clipsToBounds = YES;
```